# Input an integer, get spaced output in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on homework and I'm stumped on this problem: Write a program that prompts the user to input an integer and then outputs both the individual digits of the number and the sum of the digits. For example, it should output the individual digits of `3456` as `3` `4` `5` `6`, [...], output `4000` as
`4` `0` `0` `0`, and the individual digits of -2345 as `2` `3` `4` `5`.

Here's my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    string a;       //declares string

    cout << "Type an integer: ";        //prompts user to input an integer
    cin >> a;               //stores into string a
    cout << "There are " << a.size() << " digits in " << a << endl; //retrieves length of string a

    cout << a.at(0);

    cout << endl;

    system ("pause");       //pauses the system so user can read the screen
    return 0;       //returns 0 if program works properly
```

}

Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong/what my next step is?

Comment: Just for the best of your journey in programming, don't write comments that say "what is something" just write a comment when you want to explain "why" you wrote something that way.

Comment: Why don't you start by explaining, in English, the logic that you think you're implementing? Not in line-by-line comment style, but as an overview.

Comment: Hint: to split up an integer into digits, look into the modulus operator.

Comment: All right, so from what I understand, I need to store the input into variables depending on the number of individual digits there are in the integer. Then I need to display them all one by one separated by spaces, and then I also have to figure out the sum and display that.

Comment: Also, you should do some code indenting. That will help everyone read it.

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is that you input a number into one integer variable (probably along with the number of digits) and use techniques to separate the digits. Remember that you can just output the digit instead of storing it first too.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: I wasn't sure how to do the indenting on this website but it's indented all right on visual studio.

Comment: @RhondaWin: I edited it for you, it just has to get through the queue.

Answer (score 1):

So the steps are..

1. store the input
2. display them all one by one separated by spaces
3. figure out the sum and display that

.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a;

    cout << "Type an integer: ";

    // 1. store the input
    cin >> a;

    // 2. display them all one by one separated by spaces
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
      cout << a[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    // 3. figure out the sum and display that
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
       total += a[i] - '0';
    cout << total << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

The tricky part is getting the correct sum in step 3.

```
total += a[i] - '0';
```

Lets say for example that a[i] is the character '4'. The ASCII value of character '4' is the integer equivalent of 52, and the ASCII integer equivalent of '0' is 48. Therefore if we take '4' - '0', we will get the difference of 4, which is the integer representation we are looking for in this case.

[Here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/attachments/Resources/41901-12628-ascii-chart.png) is a simple ASCII chart with character values.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to input the number as a string. This will allow you to do digit by digit processing. Then the user will enter the number once instead of many times as digits.

Comment: I tried to do that in the for loop but there isn't a way for me to predict how many digits will be in each integer, hence why I created that for loop to make sure it would keep storing things for as long as the counter was <= the number of digits. But I still have no way of knowing how many variables I should have...

Comment: Are you allowed to use std::string?

Comment: @RhondaWin: A string has a property for its length (the number of characters). This is accessible through the method `size()`. You can use this to find how many digits there were in the string. You can then use `at()` to find the character at a certain point in the string (indexes start at 0).

Comment: I didn't even know `string::size` existed :p I always used `string::length`. I'm guessing that at this point strings are out of the question though. Same concept as arrays.

Comment: I think we're at liberty to use strings. So for example if the numbers are stored into string variable x, I could use size(x) to find out the size and then presumably store that numerical value into int variable digits? Would I have to write a loop for at()?

Comment: No. To call the method on the string it would be `someString.size()`. Same with `at()`.

Comment: So would I have to put anything in between the parentheses? Sorry if my questions are dumb but I'm just at a loss for how to approach the problem at this point

Comment: No. The method `size` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this piece of code:

```
   int num = 0;
   cin>>num;

   //Make sure array is large enough to hold all digits
   //For an int 10 digits it the max
   int digits[10] = {0};  

   //This variable tracks the count of actual number of
   //digits extracted from user input
   int digitCount = 0;

   while (num > 0) 
   {
      digits[digitCount] = num % 10;   //Extract digit at units place
      num = num / 10;                 //Advance through the number
      digitCount++;
   }

   for(int count= digitCount-1 ; count >= 0; count-- )
   {
      cout<<digits[count]<<" ";
   }
```

Note that the printing loop runs backwards (i.e from `digitCount` to `zero`) because the digits are extracted and stored starting from the units place. For a number a like `12345` the `digits` array will contain `5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: I don't know how to do arrays yet (they're at the end of this course actually)

Comment: Ok, Do you know the number of digits in the input before hand? If so, you could try stuff like: `cout << num / 10000 << " " << num / 1000 % 10 << " " << num / 100 % 100 % 10 << " "<< num / 10 % 1000 % 100 % 10 << " " << num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 % 10<< endl;` (see [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57975-algorithm-for-extracting-an-integers-digits/) for details). Also, are you allowed to use string manipulation functions like itoa?

Comment: No, I don't know. The program is supposed to be able to split apart any integer that is put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Rhonda, I can understand your frustration, computers are like that... they do what you say, not what you mean :-) Hang in there.

You say your program should output each of the digits in the number, yet your program asks the user to enter each of the digits.  That is confusing.

Also, you first assign a value to "num" here

```
cin >> num;
```

then you overwrite "num" in this line

```
cin >> num >> a;
```

I'm not sure what you mean to do here, but what you're telling the computer to do is to read an integer from the input and assign it to "num" and assign the rest to the line to string "a"... if the rest of the line just has a space, the space will be discarded... it acts as a separator.  That is probably confusing you as well.

Comment: Right, I asked the user to input the digits so they could be stored in num and a. That was the point when I realized I would never know how many variables I needed, so I just saved the .cpp and left it at that out of frustration.

Comment: Then I think you should use std::string... try to read the input number into a std::string variable and then print that out... take it one step at a time.

Comment: Right, but how am I supposed to know how many string variables I should declare?

Comment: You only need one string variable.... a string will hold an arbitrary number of "characters", presumably decimal digits but it could be any character on your keyboard.  You'll need a loop to go through each of the characters in the string.  You can query the string to find out what the length is:

    size_t count = input_string.length();

You could also use "input_string.size()" for strings both "length()" and "size()" give the same value.

Comment: Okay, I experimented with storing integers in the string variable and it worked. I've also inserted a.size() and done cout << a.size() so I know what the length of the string is.

Comment: A string variable is an "object" in C++ (more precisely it is an instance of the string class).  You can access functions associated with an object by joining the name of the variable and the name of the function you want to invoke with a "." so if your string is called input_string and you want to know the length you invoke input_string.length() and that returns the current length of the string.  This will help you http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/

Comment: You are almost there!  First you need to understand what that example code does.  It "constructs" a string variable, called "str", and initializes with a value of "Test String" which contains eleven characters.  Then it printed each of the characters, one by one.  It is almost what you need, except you want to use the string with the value you read from the input, and you want to put a space between characters. And you want to end with a "new line".  You're almost there.

Comment: Okay, while initially my program did not list all the numbers from the link you posted, I adjusted it to show the numbers from my string with spaces in between. Now I have to display the sum. You're so helpful!

Comment: Except I'm not positive on how to calculate the sum. My best guess is to include the calculation within the loop.

Comment: Well, you can convert a character in the range '0' to '9' into an integer by subtracting '0' from the character... this works because the internal representation for decimal characters are consecutive, thankfully.  So you can do something like "char c = a.at(i)" that gives you the character at position "i" in "a".  Then accumulate in your sum, by adding "c - '0'" to the sum, like so: "sum = sum + c - '0';" Or you can simplify and say "sum += a.at(i) - '0';"

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int runningTotal = 0;
    std::string inputString;
    std::cin >> inputString;
    for ( std::string::iterator _it = inputString.begin(); 
                                _it != inputString.end(); ++_it )
    {
        // *_it now represents an individual char of the input string
        char a = *_it; char* b = &a;
        if ( a != '-' )
        {
             runningTotal += atoi( std::string( b ).c_str() );
             std::cout << *_it << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Total of all digits: " << runningTotal << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    std::system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

I threw this together quickly for you. Hope it's of help.

Comment: Wow, this is really complicated and I think my prof would recognize that this is beyond what we have learned. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you like I'd be happy to explain it further, but as you say, if this is a submitted homework task your professor will probably ask questions if it hasn't been taught yet ;)

Comment: Exactly. We just started at the end of January so I don't know much

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`s yet? Because my code is written using an iterator-based loop, but could easily be replaced with a more classical looking for loop.

Comment: @AlexZ: Usually when a question has the `homework` tag, the OP doesn't want a full solution, but rather a bit of guidance.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I felt I'd just be repeating what has already been explained by others. I wanted to provide a code example to complement the other answers (perhaps I should have been more explicit about this) - in fact it goes hand in hand with yours

Comment: We're allowed to use strings/that's the way I'm tackling this anyway.